# How to define a callback that takes spreaded arguments in jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm trying to define a callback with a variable number of arguments in jsdoc, but my linter tells me that at least one argument is expected, but 0 were given.

```js
  /**
   * This is the listen equivelant for rabbit.log()
   * It uses this.listen(LOG_CHANNEL) to recieve logs
   * @param {function(...*):*} callback This gets called with the params from rabbit.log
   */
  async listenLogs(callback) {
    return await this.listen(LOG_CHANNEL, data => callback(...data));
  }
```

Edit 1:
As requested: this.listen:

```js
/**
   * To listen for a topic call this .
   * @param {String} topic Topic to subscribe to
   * @param {function(*):*} callback the callback to call for each RabbitMQ message on topic
   * @param {Object} [options={}] Further options
   * @returns {Promise<void>}
   */
  async listen(topic, callback, { durable = false } = {}) {
    /* ... */
    await channel.consume(
      queue.queue,
      msg => callback(JSON.parse(msg.content.toString())),
      { noAck: true }
    );
  }
```

Comment: please also show an example of this .listen and preferably the stacktrace

Comment: FYI, there is no point on `return await` outside of a try block. Just return the Promise directly.

Comment: @Paulpro this is a remainder of an old version, but thanks for marking this out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [jonathan heindl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11268857/jonathan-heindl) for marking out, that I should look at this.listen.

The problem was my callback definition.

Change this:

```js
/**
 * @param {function(*):*} callback
 */
```

To this:

```js
/**
 * @param {function([*]):*} callback
 */
```